# Javascript allow only text value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

**Javascript:**

```
  function textonly(e) {
        var code;
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
        var AllowRegex = /^[\ba-zA-Z\s-]$/;
        if (AllowRegex.test(character)) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" onkeypress="return textonly(event);" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am trying to allow only text.If i use textonly event in above js function,

i can not press key below:

**ğ,ü,ş,i,ö,ç** and **Space**

how can i also include above values on key press ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend your regex like this:

```
^[\ba-zA-Z\sğüşöç\s]$
```

This will allow one character of the below:

`\b` a backspace character (ASCII 8)
`a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
`A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
`\s` match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
`ğüşöç` a single character in the list ğüşöç literally (case sensitive)
`\s` match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

Comment: thanks it works except " ı " how can i also include "  ı  " ?